# Amazon DynamoDB update item depending on version

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using Boto3 for DynamoDB, and I need to update an Item periodically if the version of the new item is higher than the one we have. The Item is a rule like this:

```
          { 
           "ID": "seat_ONLINE",
           "type": "seat",
           "version":"1.0",
           "paymentMode": "ONLINE",
           "rules": [...]
          }
```

where ID is the PK for every rule. Of course I will have several different rules and I will then get a JSON with the new rule version, but I would like to know how to compare it with the rules version I already have in the DB.
The quick answer would be using a get_item of a random fixed rule, but I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to do this than getting a random rule just to check the version.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1. Scan the whole DynamoDb table to get all the rules.
2. For each entry:

   1. Compare the version you got from DynamoDb and the version you have.
   2. Update if required.